# Can't start new activity and toast won't display

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to start a new Activity when a menu item is selected. I've managed to do that for one menu item (download), but now I'm trying to do a search. However, the activity won't even start.

Hope someone can point out what I'm missing.

Thanks!

Here is the relevant code:

1) In Parent Activity. When I remove the intent, the toast shows. When I put it back in, the app crashes without showing the toast.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())   {

    case R.id.action_download:
        image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        Bitmap bmp = image.getDrawingCache();
        String name = random();

        if (MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bmp, name , "description") != null)   {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Downloaded image successfully!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
        else    {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Not successful!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }

 case R.id.action_search:
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Made it to this point!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

        Intent j = new Intent(this, GoogleSearchIntent.class);
        startActivity(j);

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

2) In Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.GoogleSearchIntent"
        android:label="@string/search_text" >

</activity>
```

Edit: I have added break statements as suggested, still no luck.

Another Edit: I changed the Intent to switch to one of my other activities. That worked FINE, so could it be my activity GoogleSearchIntent that is causing problems?

```
public class GoogleSearchIntent extends Activity {

private EditText editTextInput;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.remain);

   // editTextInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextInput);
   }

public void onSearchClick(View v)
{
    try {
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
         String term = editTextInput.getText().toString();
         intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, term);
         startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
}
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Post the stacktrace from logcat

Comment: How do I know what in the logcat is relevant?

Comment: Post logcat and full code.

Comment: Missing `break` of `case R.id.action_download:`

Comment: You have named the search Activity as __GoogleSearchIntent__ . But it extends Activity actually, right?

Comment: Yes it does extend Activity.

Comment: I don't know how to post the logcat :/ sorry

Comment: The problem was solved by fixing some improper tags in the layout for the new activity. 

Just goes to show that any small mistake can gum up the works, even if Eclipse doesn't recognize it as an error...

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to "break"

```
 case R.id.action_download:
    image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    Bitmap bmp = image.getDrawingCache();
    String name = random();

    if (MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bmp, name , "description") != null)   {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Downloaded image successfully!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
    else    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Not successful!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
    break;
    case R.id.action_search:
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Made it to this point!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);
    toast.show();

    Intent j = new Intent(this, GoogleSearchIntent.class);
    startActivity(j);
    break;

default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and you should initialize toasts in this way:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);
```

or call them in one step:

```
Toast.makeText(this, R.string.prompt_to_check_gps, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I tried this and still no luck. Thanks anyway. Also, my point about toasts was that it was working before I declared the intent. If it's crashing on the intent line, shouldn't the toast still display?

Comment: Hmm, the toast should be shown... But maybe something went wrong with your layout files at "second/receiving activity" (or button methods)

Comment: Yep, I figured it all out. There were some mistakes in the layout which weren't causing "errors", per se. But it all works now. Thanks!